# Notification centre in Lion and Facebook

Tags: macos, notifications, facebook, twitter

When notifications pop up from the notification centre for Facebook posts nothing happens when I click the show button.

If a tweet comes along the show button opens up a browser tab.

Any ideas why this isn't working for Facebook and is working for Twitter?

Comment: Just to confirm...So you get the facebook notification but you can not open facebook from notification center!

Comment: Yes exactly right. Basically the little notifications (alerts) have a close and a show button. Close works as it should, but with Facebook notifications the show button does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

OK, go to your Facebook

open your settings and go to the the Notifications

Make sure the app request and activity for OSX is checked

In Notification on your Mac click on the facebook and a window should open where you can post directly to facebook from your mac.

Comment: Ok so I had a look at all that and I am able to post to Facebook already from the notification centre. It is more to do with the actual notification I get (the alert). It has a button called show, which when you click on it is supposed to open a browser window (which it does with the twitter notifications) and doesn't with the facebook notifications.

Comment: Reinstall the Facebook. Remove it in System Preference @Mail,contacts,calender and install again. If that does not do it do the Restore Permissions.